# Typescript - Omit props types of HoC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have `withDataTableQuery` HoC which has functionality like fetching and passing data, etc... for `DataTable` component. This HoC is connected to redux store, which contains data and they are passed to `withDataTableQuery` through props which are then passed to `DataTable` component.

I want to have access to `data` property inside my HoC and `DataTable` component... just want to have it strongly typed so when I type `props.data`, typescript will know about that.

HoC code below

```
export interface IWithDataTableQueryProps {
    data: any[];
    //some other props
}

export const withDataTableQuery = (Component) => (props: IWithDataTableQueryProps) => {
    // code
    return <Component
        data={props.data}
        //rest of code
    />;
}
```

DataTable component which is wrapped with HoC

```
export interface IDataTableProps {
    columns: Array<any>;
}

export const DataTable = withDataTableQuery((props: IDataTableProps & IWithDataTableQueryProps) => {
    // code removed for brevity
    return <>{props.data.map(x=> <Row {...x} />)}</>
})
```

I have some view which I render under some url, and this view component contains
`DataTable` component. Right now I have to do something like `data={[]}` to satisfy typescript checking that I passed data prop, which is defined by `IWithDataTableQueryProps` interface, but this is unwanted since this is passed from my HoC, I just want to specify what columns will be rendered, so something like this

```
export const View = () => {
    return <DataTable
        columns={columns}
        // data={[]} -> I dont want to specify data prop here just to satisfy TS, 
        // I have to Omit this props somehow
    />
};
```

Comment: it is not clear what exactly you would like to do and how should it word. Did IGraphQlProps or IConstructor has the "columns" property inside?

Comment: What about passing a generic type?

Comment: @dm.shpak I updated question

Comment: @alieslamifard I can give it a try, but not exactly sure, if it will work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the TypeScript `Omit` utility?

I'm not exactly sure about the implementation in your code, but you can create a new interface by extending a type that uses the other interface, but omits any keys that you don't want...

```
type IWithDataTableQueryPropsNoData  = Omit<IWIthDataTableQueryProps, 'data'>

export interface IDataTableProps extends IWithDataTableQueryPropsNoData = {
   columns: Array<any>
}

export const DataTable = (props: IDataTableProps) => {
    // code removed for brevity
    return <>{props.data.map(x=> <Row {...x} />)}</>
}
```